# easeOutBack animation and Magnet Effect

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas

is there some steering behaviors algorithm that I can set to make this effect ?
https://gifyu.com/image/EMJ6

many nodes are connected to each other and move randomly

Thanks!

Comment: this seems like a balance of nodes attracting and repelling each other

Comment: yes, but how to implement similar effect ? any algorithm ? Thanks

Comment: well you have a position, a velocity that changes position and some force that change velocity. Every node interacts with every other node withhin a certain range. The force is the sum of the attraction betwen the nodes, usually divided by `distance²`, and the repelling if they are too close; and maybe some random force each frame, that simply makes the nodes always move. The rest should be playing around with multipliers.

Comment: If this is still too complicated/vague for you try something simpler first: a single object *(can be as simple as a box)* that you can accellerate with your arrow keys *(the longer you press, the faster it gets)*, and that keep moving when you stop pressing the keys or that decellerate when you press the key for the opposite direction. That should give you some basig understanding of an objects position, velocity and applying forces to it.